# What's a good Developmental Tool for Extracting Bookmark to Page No. Mapping From pdf?

Tags: software-development, pdf, bookmark, file-converter, data-extraction

I want to extract the page numbers of bookmarks from .pdf files. I need to be able to pass filename and it should yield:

```
Bookmark    Page Number
loophard    3
leetfart    45
seedmart    68
```

as output that can be used in a script.

## Specs:

1. Must run on Windows
2. Must be automatizable
3. Must be free
4. Ideally lightweight & fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my software in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143900/267786). I was able to construct the .bat script:

```
java -jar jpdftweak.jar "in.pdf" -savebookmarks "out.csv"
```